# Browsing for other users in app (android)

Tags: java, android, database, facebook

I've created a facebook login profile view for a user in my application. I'd like a way for the users who login via facebook, google or are just registered in general, can search for each other, and view each others profiles. How do i do that? I suppose i would need some sort of database with all registered users, although i dont know how to make that. Perhaps a bit like the way facebook let people search for each other - how do they achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'll need to hava DB on you own server to store the list on all registered user. Then when an user opens your app, the app will make a request to that DB for the list of all users. Then you can use those usernames to show their profiles on Facebook, Google+ or other services they used to register.

For the DB you can use any SQL DB like mySQL. To access the DB you'll need to make some API for example using SOAP. For the server, any WWW hosting will do, MySQL and PHP is all you need.